metaplex umi - InterfaceImplementationMissingError: Tried using TransactionFactoryInterface but no implementation of that interface was found
I'm trying to use metaplex/umi but I get an error.
frontend (vue.js v3):
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi';

const test = async (transaction_value) => {
    const umi = createUmi(url);
    const transaction_array = Buffer.from(transaction_value, 'base64');
    const transaction = umi.transactions.deserialize(transaction_array);
    //error//
    ...
}

Error:
InterfaceImplementationMissingError: Tried using TransactionFactoryInterface but no implementation of that interface was found. Make sure an implementation is registered, e.g. via "context.transactions = new MyTransactionFactory();".
Why does the error occur? How to solve the problem?

You're importing the "some assembly required" Umi interface. It's recommended to instead import createUmi from umi-bundle-defaults which includes the default interfaces you're expecting.
